# Display group having certain value only on max date and not in other entries of group

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, group-by, oracle12c

I am looking to display the group which is grouped on id column where `trans_cd='Audit'` only on max trans_proc_dt of that group. There should not be any other `trans_cd='Audit'` execpt for max trans_proc_dt.

```
    ID  TRANS_PROC_DT   TRANS_CD    TRANS_AMT
165     5/13/2020       Renewal         553
165     10/22/2020      Cancellation    -376
165     11/24/2020      Audit   3
165     6/2/2021        Change  0
165     6/2/2021        Audit   -7
165     6/3/2021        Audit   0
497     5/1/2020        Renewal 1394
497     1/11/2021       Cancellation    -578
497     2/10/2021       Audit   -3
497     4/28/2021       Audit   76
497     5/12/2021       Audit   -73
497     6/2/2021        Change  0
511     4/27/2020       Renewal 4409
511     7/30/2020       Change  0
511     10/5/2020       Cancellation    -2558
511     2/18/2021       Audit   2806
577     5/15/2020       Renewal 829
577     2/12/2021       Audit   -123
577     4/28/2021       Audit   118
577     5/12/2021       Audit   5
577     6/2/2021        Change  0
577     6/2/2021        Audit   -5
577     6/3/2021        Audit   0
577     12/4/2020       Renewal 1996
577     6/2/2021        Change  0
751     5/13/2020       Renewal 1307
751     1/28/2021       Cancellation    -523
751     3/3/2021        Audit   481
751     4/28/2021       Audit   120
751     5/12/2021       Audit   -601
751     6/2/2021        Change  0
751     6/2/2021        Audit   601
751     6/3/2021        Audit   0
984     5/13/2020       Renewal 1081
984     11/2/2020       Change  0
984     6/3/2021        Audit   0
```

My output should be

```
ID  TRANS_PROC_DT   TRANS_CD    TRANS_AMT
511     4/27/2020       Renewal 4409
511     7/30/2020       Change  0
511     10/5/2020       Cancellation    -2558
511     1/27/2021       Renewal 4409
511     2/18/2021       Audit   2806
984     5/13/2020       Renewal 1081
984     11/2/2020       Change  0
984     6/3/2021        Audit   0
```

I can't think how to go about getting my result set.

Comment: I don't quite follow the logic to get the results you show. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use analytic functions to calculate absolute maximum date and minimum date of `Audit` code per group, then compare them: if no more such transactions occurred on other dates, they should be equal.

> ```
> with a(ID, TRANS_PROC_DT, TRANS_CD, TRANS_AMT) as (
> select 165, '5/13/2020', 'Renewal', 553 from dual union all
> select 165, '10/22/2020', 'Cancellation', -376 from dual union all
> select 165, '11/24/2020', 'Audit', 3 from dual union all
> select 165, '6/2/2021', 'Change', 0 from dual union all
> select 165, '6/2/2021', 'Audit', -7 from dual union all
> select 165, '6/3/2021', 'Audit', 0 from dual union all
> select 497, '5/1/2020', 'Renewal', 1394 from dual union all
> select 497, '1/11/2021', 'Cancellation', -578 from dual union all
> select 497, '2/10/2021', 'Audit', -3 from dual union all
> select 497, '4/28/2021', 'Audit', 76 from dual union all
> select 497, '5/12/2021', 'Audit', -73 from dual union all
> select 497, '6/2/2021', 'Change', 0 from dual union all
> select 511, '4/27/2020', 'Renewal', 4409 from dual union all
> select 511, '7/30/2020', 'Change', 0 from dual union all
> select 511, '10/5/2020', 'Cancellation', -2558 from dual union all
> select 511, '2/18/2021', 'Audit', 2806 from dual union all
> select 577, '5/15/2020', 'Renewal', 829 from dual union all
> select 577, '2/12/2021', 'Audit', -123 from dual union all
> select 577, '4/28/2021', 'Audit', 118 from dual union all
> select 577, '5/12/2021', 'Audit', 5 from dual union all
> select 577, '6/2/2021', 'Change', 0 from dual union all
> select 577, '6/2/2021', 'Audit', -5 from dual union all
> select 577, '6/3/2021', 'Audit', 0 from dual union all
> select 577, '12/4/2020', 'Renewal', 1996 from dual union all
> select 577, '6/2/2021', 'Change', 0 from dual union all
> select 751, '5/13/2020', 'Renewal', 1307 from dual union all
> select 751, '1/28/2021', 'Cancellation', -523 from dual union all
> select 751, '3/3/2021', 'Audit', 481 from dual union all
> select 751, '4/28/2021', 'Audit', 120 from dual union all
> select 751, '5/12/2021', 'Audit', -601 from dual union all
> select 751, '6/2/2021', 'Change', 0 from dual union all
> select 751, '6/2/2021', 'Audit', 601 from dual union all
> select 751, '6/3/2021', 'Audit', 0 from dual union all
> select 984, '5/13/2020', 'Renewal', 1081 from dual union all
> select 984, '11/2/2020', 'Change', 0 from dual union all
> select 984, '6/3/2021', 'Audit', 0 from dual
> )
> , last_dt as (
>   select
>     a.*
>     , min(
>        case trans_cd
>        when 'Audit'
>        then to_date(TRANS_PROC_DT, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
>        end
>     ) over(partition by id)
>     as audit_dt
>     , max(to_date(TRANS_PROC_DT, 'mm/dd/yyyy'))
>       over(partition by id)
>     as max_dt
>
>   from a
> )
> select
>   id
>   , trans_proc_dt
>   , trans_cd
>   , trans_amt
> from last_dt
> where max_dt = audit_dt
> order by id, to_date(TRANS_PROC_DT, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
> ```

> ```
>  ID | TRANS_PROC_DT | TRANS_CD     | TRANS_AMT
> --: | :------------ | :----------- | --------:
> 511 | 4/27/2020     | Renewal      |      4409
> 511 | 7/30/2020     | Change       |         0
> 511 | 10/5/2020     | Cancellation |     -2558
> 511 | 2/18/2021     | Audit        |      2806
> 984 | 5/13/2020     | Renewal      |      1081
> 984 | 11/2/2020     | Change       |         0
> 984 | 6/3/2021      | Audit        |         0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=80469ed4d1fb310461b66708d0cf4775)*

Answer (score 0):

You may try below -

```
Select
   * 
from
   tableName tn 
where
   ID not in 
   (
      Select
         ID 
      from
         tableName t 
      where
         trans_cd = 'Audit' 
         and TRANS_PROC_DT <> (
         Select
            max(TRANS_PROC_DT) 
         from
            tableName t1 
         where
            t1.ID = t.ID) 
   )
```